# Two side by side UITableView scroll simultaneously

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, tableview

I have two `UITableView` side by side in one `UIViewController`.I want these tableViews to scroll simultaneously. Here I have used `contentOffset`. But the problem is that when I try to scroll the table view by touching right tableView it is working. But when I try to scroll the table view by touching the left tableView it is not working. How to scroll them at a time by touching any of the tableView?

Here is my code -

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    tableViewTwo.contentSize.height = tableViewOne.contentSize.height
    tableViewOne.contentOffset = tableViewTwo.contentOffset

}
```

Comment: Step 1, check which one is being scrolled(argument scrollView), create if statement Step 2 replicate your code but reverse assignments for one if/else if branch, e.g. `tableViewTwo.contentOffset = tableViewOne.contentOffset`. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == tableView1 {
        tableView2.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
        tableView2.contentSize.height = scrollView.contentSize.height
    } else {
        tableView1.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
        tableView1.contentSize.height = scrollView.contentSize.height
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I expand this code to make it work for 4 tableviews?